# No more video output over USB-C

Tags: display, usb, displayport

I bought an LG 27UK600 a while ago, to go with my 2016 Macbook Pro. It worked perfectly for about 3 months, until a few days ago, when the Macbook's display did something weird (some strange colors) and the external display didn't turn on anymore.

I thought at first that my cable was dead (USB C > DisplayPort), but after buying a new one, I see no change in behaviour.

When I remove the Displayport-side from the display, it recognises a cable is removed (or plugged in), so it doesn't seem to be the screen.

All USB-C ports on my Macbook can be used for charging, and my USB-dongle (3x USB 3.0, HDMI and SD card) works without hassle. Even the HDMI-output works perfectly fine on the display.

I have tried resetting NVRAM, booting in safe mode, resetting SMC and just regular rebooting, but nothing helps; when I plug the USB-C in, there is no reaction.

I'm going to do some more resets of the above, to see if I did it wrong in some way, but I would like to know if anyone has tried the same, or if there are some more things I could try?

Edit: After a comment, here are some screenshots from my "System Report". There's no change when I plug a USB-C-cable in.[image: Radeon Pro 450 System report]
[image: Intel HD Graphics 530 system report]

Edit 2: I didn't power-cycle the monitor, because I figured the fault was on my Macbook Pro's side. However, after doing that, the monitor works like a charm again.

Comment: I reset NVRAM/PRAM: No luck. I reset SMC: No luck. It's like USB-C > DisplayPort is just not recognised anymore.

Comment: From what you wrote in the first paragraph, " *...the Macbook's display did something weird (some strange colors) and the external display didn't turn on anymore.* " Sounds suspiciously like an issue with one of the video cards in your MacBook. Go to Apple Menu > About This Mac > System Report >Graphics Displays and add the results of that to your original question with and without the monitor connected.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have taken some screenshots and added them to the question. There's no difference between with or without the USB-C cable.

Comment: Oh my... I figured that I didn't power cycle the monitor yet, and guess what: it works like a charm again. So weird.

Comment: Glad yu got it working, it's often the simple things that slip your mind that fixes it.

Comment: Please don't write SOLVED into the question, this won't help future visitors. Post your solution as an answer below and accept it instead