# No video output over USB-C

Tags: display, usb, displayport, thunderbolt-display

I recently purchased a DELL U2719DC Display. Ive had the display for about 2 months with no issues. I'm using it with a MBP ~2018(only has usb c ports). Since yesterday I can't get the display to work over USB-C. The odd thing is the display is still working as a USB hub, I have a keyboard and camera plugged directly into the monitor and the monitor is connected to the laptop via USB-C. I'm able to use both devices but there's no display output. I have tried the following things:

1. Reset the monitor and laptop
2. Reset NVRAM/PRAM
3. Reset SMC
4. Manually changing the display inputs
5. Using another usb-c cable rated for display
6. Testing the original cable on another display, the cable works fine.
7. Connecting to the other video output options. It has HDMI & Display Port, these work fine
8. Using the monitor's display menu, resetting the monitors settings
9. I checked the test in the [Dell's Manual on Page 52](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_monitors/dell-u2719dc-monitor_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf), the monitor colors are fine and I haven't gotten any messages from the self diagnostic.
10. I tried another USB-C monitor(Dell U2720Q) in all of my MBP's USB-C ports and it works fine.
11. Tried the monitor in question with a different cable in all of the USB-C ports. does not work.

Unfortunately nothing seems to get the display to work over USB-C. If anyone has any suggestion that would be great.

Comment: When you connect the monitor, does it show up in System Preferences => Displays? (press Gather Windows to get them all on one display)

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn’t show up under displays.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I have the exact same problem but with my Mac mini.

Comment: Seems to be a similar issue to this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358676/no-more-video-output-over-usb-c although in my case power cycling the monitor did not help.